# Problem with MySQL database after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

We have an old server that until yesterday was running a 2016 version of Ubuntu. The server was super fast (providing a complex page in less than 1 second). As we needed PHP8.2, we decided to upgrade to Ubuntu22.

After the upgrade the system is very slow and the same page take about 30 seconds to generate!!!!

After investigation I believe the problem is due to MySQL. Prior to upgrade our database was as follow:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: website
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `articleBookmarks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articleBookmarks`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `articleBookmarks` (
  `bookmarkId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `articleId` char(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addDate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookmarkId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=99 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

after upgrade I have

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.36, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: website
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `articleBookmarks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articleBookmarks`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `articleBookmarks` (
  `bookmarkId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `articleId` char(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `addDate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookmarkId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=135 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

It seems that ubuntu decides to change/convert the character set from utf8 to utf8mb4 without asking!

As a result the database display all emoji and spacial symbols wrongly. For example the smile emoji is displayed now as "ðŸ˜‚".

In addition I cannot insert anymore records in the database. I receive the following error:

> [Tue Mar 26 15:27:25.623713 2024] [php:error] [pid 4341] [client 40.xx.xxx.xxx:52355] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Conversion from collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci into latin1_swedish_ci impossible for parameter in /var/www/html/MyPHPfunction.php:8630\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/MyPHPfunction.php(8630): mysqli_stmt->execute()\n#1 /var/www/html/funct2.php(398): show_search_results()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/funct2.php on line 8630

I could not find any table with latin1_swedish_ci

Does anyone know how this can be fixed? the full server is somehow useless at the moment :(

Edit: This is the table definition

```
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field            | Type           | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id               | int            | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| fromId           | char(20)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| toId             | char(20)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| date             | datetime       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| readIt           | int            | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| readDate         | datetime       | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| notificat_sent   | int            | YES  |     | 0                 |                   |
| msg              | text           | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| picture          | char(100)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
| audio            | char(100)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

and this is the error message

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `website`.`privateMsg`
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `audio` varbinary(100),
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `fromId` varbinary(20),
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `msg` blob,
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `picture` varbinary(100),
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `toId` varbinary(20);
Query OK, 10644 rows affected (0.39 sec)
Records: 10644  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `website`.`privateMsg`
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `audio` char(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `fromId` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `msg` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `picture` char(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    -> MODIFY COLUMN `toId` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    -> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xC3 cono...' for column 'msg' at row 7573
mysql>
```

output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%';`

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                 |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                               |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                               |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                               |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                               |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                               |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                                               |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/                        |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Solution:
stackoverflow closed this request, but I would like to provide everyone the solution, as I guess many in the future will cry as I did yesterday :P

After receiving the error because of the illegal symbol in the cell, I had input the following:

```
select id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowID, CONVERT(`msg` USING ASCII) from privateMsg LIMIT 123,1;
```

Where '123' is the broken-row in the message ERROR 1366 (HY000): ...

The output is the following

```
+-----+-------+----------------------------+
| id  | RowID | CONVERT(`msg` USING ASCII) |
+-----+-------+----------------------------+
| 129 |   123 | Hello :)                   |
+-----+-------+----------------------------+
```

As you can see the table above shows the "real" id of the record in the database as well as the RowId calculated by MySQL (That is surprisingly different O_o, BTW, why mysql provide the wrong index??? mystery!!!). The message converted into ASCII helps to identify the problematic character. Then open a text editor (No need to go with hex) and import the database (the file generated by mysqldump), search the string (Hello :) in my case), replace the bad-character, save the file, import the edited-database in MySQL and iterate until all wrong symbols have been removed.

I hope this can be of your help in the future :)

PS: Oracle, if you are reading, please improve MySQL by providing better error messages. There is a lot that can be done to make it more user friendly!

Comment: `latin1_swedish_ci` is the default collation for the `latin1` character set. If you change the server's default character set (or set the charset at connection) back to `latin1`, then your application will _probably_ function as it did before. **This is not a fix** but will continue to mask the underlying issue, as it did before. If you are storing UTF-8 chars you should change your tables to utf8mb4, as the chars will be incorrectly encoded in your latin1 columns. You should have a read through this - [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have decided to convert all database to UTF-8. it is enought to run "ALTER TABLE myTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4" on each table or do I have to do something more ?

Comment: Thank you. I have done a copy of the database. I will try the conversion process but seems very complex :( How can I generate the ALTER statement from the information_schema ? Do I have to write an ALTER for each single column of each table ? This is going to take ages ...

Comment: Also, about being very slow, try what happens if you connect using `127.0.0.1` or `::1` instead of `localhost` in your app's DB config. This is an issue I had in the past on a server (although I was unable to figure out the root cause).

Comment: Thank you CherryDT :) I have added ServerName 127.0.0.1 to the apache configuration file and now the server is faster again

Answer (score 1):

**It is really important that you confirm you have a usable backup before making mass changes like this and test the changes on a copy before running against any production data.**

It seems most likely that you have ended up with UTF-8 chars stored in your latin1 columns. Before your database server upgrade, both the connection and column character sets were latin1, so when reading and/or writing to the db no implicit character conversion was occurring. Now that the default character set is utf8mb4, the connection is utf8mb4 but the columns are latin1. This leads to an implicit character conversion which mangles your data.

To confirm the above assumption, run the following SELECT against a table/column that you know contains data that is displaying incorrectly. It is important that you do this over utf8mb4 connection.

```sql
SELECT `name`, CONVERT(CONVERT(`name` USING binary) USING utf8mb4)
FROM `your_db_name`.`test1`;
```

I would expect the first column to contain the mangled version and the second one to be correct.

If the above confirms the suspected scenario, you can use the information_schema to write all the ALTER TABLE statements. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '`\n',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        '\tMODIFY COLUMN `', COLUMN_NAME, '` ',
        IF(DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'char'), CONCAT('varbinary(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')'), 'blob'),
        IF(IS_NULLABLE = 'NO', ' NOT NULL', ''),
        IF(COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('DEFAULT \'', COLUMN_DEFAULT, '\''), '')
        SEPARATOR ',\n'
    ),
    ';\n'
    'ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '`\n',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        '\tMODIFY COLUMN `', COLUMN_NAME, '` ',
        COLUMN_TYPE, ' CHARACTER SET utf8mb4',
        IF(IS_NULLABLE = 'NO', ' NOT NULL', ''),
        IF(COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('DEFAULT \'', COLUMN_DEFAULT, '\''), '')
        SEPARATOR ',\n'
    ),
    ',\n\tDEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;\n'
) AS `alter_stmt`
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name'
AND DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'char', 'text')
AND CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'latin1'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Given a simple table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `your_db_name`.`test1` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `col1` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

the above query will output something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `your_db_name`.`test1`
    MODIFY COLUMN `name` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN `description` blob NOT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN `col1` varbinary(2);
ALTER TABLE `your_db_name`.`test1`
    MODIFY COLUMN `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN `col1` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

You can modify the info schema query to add the appropriate collation and column comments if needed.

Comment: I am running the script and I am receiving errors like "ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xAB\xAB D \xC5...'". Probably I have used string instead of mb_string. The conversion does not proceed unfortunately! How can be solved? I have a lot or rows with this error and I do not want to remove them from the database

Comment: why is MySQL so complicated! :(

Comment: I would like to add that this error is only for 500 lines out of 10000. Part of the database seems to be converted well (i see emoji ...), but for some records i received the error. any help ?

Comment: I have added the requested info. This is the output provided by the server now. Previously it was running a different version of ubuntu/mysql. If in some fields some symbols are broken is not a big problem. I have notice that the majority of the data is properly converted and this is fine to me.  Is there a way to not convert the problematic fields and move on ? can this error be disabled somehow ?

Comment: i have many rows with this problem. I guess the best is to do a 1 step conversion instead of 2 steps for the affected columns. In this way I will have the database coded in UTF8 and running again by tomorrow. Then with PHP i will do a replace 1 by one of all emoji and wrong symbols. It is a lot of work but what else should I do ? Mysql is really bad implemented!

Comment: I cannot hex-edit several GB of data!

Comment: Thank you very much :) You helped me a lot. I appreciate. The server has more than 10 DB (> 4GB of data) and I have this problems also in some other tables. With your script I am able to convert more than 90% of the data, that is very good :) On the affected columns I will do a single step conversion and then replace each symbol with a PHP script. BTW I believe MySQL should replace the wrong symbol with an exclamation mark and continue the conversion. How it behaves is not OK! The old MySQL 5 should have done a check on the input data and garantee data-integrity. PHP cannot be blamed, i guess.

Comment: I have managed to convert the full database. I have updated the initial request with the solution :)